# Web Installer Issue -DB Issue -The server principal "DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$" is not able to access the database

Tags: web, installation, visual-studio-2019

I am getting below error while generating the SQL scripts using a  web installer with Integrated security as true /Windows authentication mode on.

It works perfectly fine with SQL authentication mode.

The server principal "DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$" is not able to access the database "" under the current security context.

Regards

Comment: What project did you use? And what step did you do to cause this behavior? Can you describe your issue in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

> Web Installer Issue -DB Issue -The server principal
> “DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$” is not able to access the database

**First**, if you access a private database by your current account, you should make sure that your current account is under the domain.

**Then**, if you have `web.config` file in your project, add `<identity impersonate="false" />` under `<system.web>`.

===================

**If you use SQL Server**,

**1)** login into it and check whether you can access the database's info. Or just change another

**2)** Go to SQL Server --> Security --> Logins and right click on NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and select Properties

In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the **User Mapping** tab. Then, on the **User Mapping** tab, select the desired database – especially the database for which this error message is displayed. On the lower screen, check the role db_owner. Click OK.

=================

**If use you SSMS**,

Open SSMS --> **Security** --> **Logins**.
Right click `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` and Click **Properties**.
Go to **Status** tab and set Permission to Connect To Database Engine To `Grant`.

==================

**If you use IIS manager**,

open IIS manager-->your **application pool** --> **advanced setting**-->set **custom account** under **Identity** menu-->then enter your domain user name(DOMAIN\USERNAME) and password.

Or you could just click **Identity**--> slectBuild-in Account and choose `NetworkService`.